# Continue after user done captcha Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bots, captcha

I am automating something for a website and at some point, the user has to manually fill out a captcha. How would I wait until the user correctly finishes the captcha to continue?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188276/cant-submit-captcha-textfield-python-selenium): "CAPTCHA ... is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try!"

Answer (score 0):

There are some of things you can do depending upon how your page behave that you are automating, its hard to exactly say with out looking at the page

1. If your save button does not enable until user put the captcha you can run a for loop and only break if the button is enabled
2. If your save button does not let move forward without putting the captcha and that check its doing at java script lever without reloading the page, you can just keep clicking the button in a for loop with a wait after each click.
3. You can also check the textbox where user put the captch in a for loop and can only break the for loop when user type certain number of char.

these are some ideas.