# Cant submit Captcha textfield Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, submit, recaptcha, captcha

**Cant submit Captcha textfield in python selenium**

Hello everyone,
I want to submit a textfield which is filled with the Code for Captcha, but I can't submit it.

This is the Error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmw4e.png)

This is my script(it works perfectly on other webpages):

**sub = driver.find_element_by_class_name("g-recaptcha-response")

sub.submit()**

have tried also a lot of other things, but nothing worked.

Here the HTML-Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hyi.png)
The Textfield is that in the whole bottom.

I would be very happy, if someone can help me. Thank you for you time!

Ps: This is my first Question, so sorry, if I did something wrong. And I am not from the USA or England, so my English is a bit bad...

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error occurs is that you are trying to find a specific element before it is rendered.
To put it simply, the web page is not ready yet, but it is a problem that occurs when you try to scrape information.

```
sub = driver.find_element_by_class_name("g-recaptcha-response")
sub.submit()
```

Edit it!

Answer (score -1):

From official Selenium [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/captchas/):

> CAPTCHA, short for Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart, is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try!

What you could do instead is

- Disable CAPTCHAs in your test environment
- Add a hook to allow tests to bypass the CAPTCHA